# Empty list appending in the same list. Why it is [[...]] instead of []

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Trying below simple code with list.

```
a = []
a.append(a)
print(a)
```

Getting below output.

```
[[...]]
```

Why are the three dots inside?

Comment: You've created a loop where `a[0] = a` so the `...` is representing the infinite depth of the list.

Comment: Why were you expecting it to not change? Maybe you meant `a.extend(a)`?